# What is different meaning between "I run him up the stairs" and "I make him run up the stairs."

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

What is different meaning between "I run him up the stairs" and "I make him run up the stairs."

Is Former situation I am with him, and latter situation I am without him?

Comment: If you run him up the stairs, it implies that you run with him. If you make him run up the stairs, there is no such implication (although, practically speaking, everyone who is run up the stairs is *made* to run up the stairs, and it is not an absolute requirement that you accompany the person you are running up the stairs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say "ran him" up the stairs it does *somewhat* imply that you ran with him, but I think this is more context than absolute meaning.  However it does imply that you had your *attention* on him the entire time -- that you were somehow *motivating* him to keep running.

For example:

> Before the race, we started up our drone and **ran it** through the course a few times to familiarize ourselves with the twists and turns.

Obviously we weren't "running" (flying) with the drone, but merely taking it through the course remotely.  But our *attention* was on the drone the entire time, as we were in control of it.

On the other hand:

> The drill sergeant forced the recruits out of their bunks long before dawn then **ran them** around the base over and over until the sun came up, yelling at them the entire time.

Here it's clear that the sergeant ran with the recruits, and had his attention on them the entire time.

Meanwhile, "made him run up the stairs" is less specific. It does imply coercion, but beyond that it depends on the context.

Comment: Along your writing, Why couldn't the verb 'open' function as the verb 'run' in the sentence "I run him up the stairs" ? I think that, if 'open' functioned like run in that comtext, this sentence is also correct "I open him the door"(this situation is that I shout to him to open the door only by his power.)  Might my thought be correct? Or if not, could you explain this why is not correct?

Comment: In your other question I linked to the explanation on ELU:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door  .  It's a good explanation although perhaps not entire complete.